# Listing all the partitions from BigQuery partitioned table with require_partition_filter

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find a way to list the partitions of a table created with `require_partition_filter = true` however I am not able to find the way yet.

This is table creation script

```
CREATE TABLE mydataset.partitionedtable_partitiontime
(
x INT64 \
)
PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)
OPTIONS(
require_partition_filter = true
);
```

Some test rows

```
INSERT INTO mydataset.partitionedtable_partitiontime (_PARTITIONTIME, x) SELECT TIMESTAMP("2017-05-01"), 10;
INSERT INTO mydataset.partitionedtable_partitiontime (_PARTITIONTIME, x) SELECT TIMESTAMP("2017-04-01"), 20;
INSERT INTO mydataset.partitionedtable_partitiontime (_PARTITIONTIME, x) SELECT TIMESTAMP("2017-03-01"), 30;
```

As expected, If  a try the following query to get the partitions, I am getting an error because I need to user a filter on top of the partitioning column

```
SELECT _PARTITIONTIME as pt, FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y%m%d", _PARTITIONTIME) as partition_id
FROM `mydataset.partitionedtable_partitiontime`
GROUP BY _PARTITIONTIME
ORDER BY _PARTITIONTIME
```

Error

```
Cannot query over table 'mydataset.partitionedtable_partitiontime' without a filter over column(s) '_PARTITION_LOAD_TIME', '_PARTITIONDATE', '_PARTITIONTIME' that can be used for partition elimination
```

any ideas how to list the partitions?

EDIT: I know that it is possible to add the filter, but I am looking for a solution like "SHOW PARTITIONS TABLENAME" of Hive to list all the partitions (which are essentially metadata)

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is the way to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM `mydataset.partitionedtable_partitiontime$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__`
```

The `bigquery.jobs.create` permission is required.

EDIT: Now is possible to get this information using Standard SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `myproject.mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE table_name = 'partitionedtable'
```

Comment: Edited to make clearer that the Standard SQL query just needs the table name (which would only include a partition time in the name if you are adding that).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [hlagos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829426/hlagos), you can get this data by querying the `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo column, in case you are using **Standard SQL**, or the `__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__` meta table for **Legacy SQL**.

You can take a look on [this GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#listing_partitions_in_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables) that contains detailed information about the usage of this partitioned tables metadata.